# In regard with an image classification machine learning basic exercise in python

Tags: python, label, artificial-intelligence, classification

Sorry because this code contains comments about the exercise in Spanish. The thing is, I am trying to train 3 models with 3 different algorithms of machine learning which are in charge of image classification based on labels. I got to a point where, I have created a dataframe in pandas that contains, a column for the images, and a column for each image labels. At the beggining I am showing some code of how do I create the image, the thing is, I get them from a data file which is binary encoded. I use unpickle to uncode it, obtaining a dictionary with all the images. I build the images using np.dstack() with the 3 channels of color of the image, this is the input that is given for us. I think the problem is with the dimensions of the images because, each image in the panda's dataframe columns size's is (32x32x3), mainly because each image is 32x32 pixels, and contains 3 layers of color red green and blue. I am getting errors all the time regarding "ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence". I think I am no way near close to getting this right. I have tried using the function flatten but it seems like it does not work either. What should I do to adapt the input? I am very lost right now, have tried everything.

```
# Los datos de cada entidad contienen los valores de la imagen. La imagen se obtiene por la combinación de tres canales/capas (red, green, blue) de la siguiente forma:
ch0 = d0[0:1024]
ch1 = d0[1024:2048]
ch2 = d0[2048:]

# Cada canal es una capa del correspondiente color
ch0 = np.reshape(ch0, (32,32)) # red
ch1 = np.reshape(ch1, (32,32)) # green
ch2 = np.reshape(ch2, (32,32)) # blue

# La combinación de ellas da una imagen con los tres colores:
image = np.dstack((ch0, ch1, ch2))


fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(2, 2))
ax.imshow(image)
plt.show()

import random as r
import cv2

categoriasAleatorias = []

for i in range(3):
    num = r.randint(0,19)
    categoriasAleatorias.append(dataMeta[b'coarse_label_names'][num])

print(categoriasAleatorias)

#Para cada imagen.

columnaImagenes = []
columnaEtiquetas = []


for i in range (len(data[b'data'])):

    if dataMeta[b'coarse_label_names'][data[b'coarse_labels'][i]] in categoriasAleatorias:
        columnaEtiquetas.append(dataMeta[b'coarse_label_names'][data[b'coarse_labels'][i]])

        # Cada entidad, se encuentra en una posición de cada uno de los anteriores atributos
        # Vamos a ver la entidad '0'
        d0 = data[b'data'][i]
        # Los datos de cada entidad contienen los valores de la imagen. La imagen se obtiene por la        combinación de tres canales/capas (red, green, blue) de la siguiente forma:
        ch0 = d0[0:1024]
        ch1 = d0[1024:2048]
        ch2 = d0[2048:]

        # Cada canal es una capa del correspondiente color
        ch0 = np.reshape(ch0, (32,32)) # red
        ch1 = np.reshape(ch1, (32,32)) # green
        ch2 = np.reshape(ch2, (32,32)) # blue

        # La combinación de ellas da una imagen con los tres colores:
        image = np.dstack((ch0, ch1, ch2))
        columnaImagenes.append(image)
print(len(columnaEtiquetas))
print(len(columnaImagenes))

df = pd.DataFrame({'etiqueta': columnaEtiquetas, 'imagen': columnaImagenes})

from sklearn.svm import SVC
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsClassifier
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score
from sklearn.preprocessing import MultiLabelBinarizer


X_train = df['imagen']
y_train = df['etiqueta']



# Crear el modelo SVM
svm = SVC()

# Entrenar el modelo SVM
svm.fit(X_train, y_train)

# Crear el modelo de Random Forest
rfc = RandomForestClassifier()

# Entrenar el modelo de Random Forest
rfc.fit(X_train, y_train)

# Crear el modelo de KNN
knn = KNeighborsClassifier()

# Entrenar el modelo de KNN
knn.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

flatten(), reshape() nothing seems to work

When I do this :

```
print(len(columnaEtiquetas))
print(len(columnaImagenes))
print(columnaImagenes[0].shape)

df = pd.DataFrame({'etiqueta': columnaEtiquetas, 'imagen': columnaImagenes})
print(df.head()) 

I obtain this: 

7500
7500
(32, 32, 3)
             etiqueta                                             imagen
0  b'food_containers'  [[[178, 168, 176], [175, 165, 173], [175, 165,...
1            b'trees'  [[[254, 254, 254], [255, 255, 255], [255, 255,...
2            b'trees'  [[[152, 71, 119], [154, 77, 124], [152, 84, 13...
3            b'trees'  [[[153, 157, 168], [155, 160, 167], [162, 168,...
4            b'trees'  [[[48, 78, 134], [51, 88, 148], [53, 86, 150],...
```

This is how my images are made,32x32pixels and 32x32x3 because there is 3 layers of color, I do not know how to fit this data or transform it in a way that the model gets it, tried your line of work to the image but kept giving me same exception.

Comment: I think it would be more clear on how to help you if you could post the example record from the dataframe and also the exact error and where you get it.

Comment: I have edited de post with some output, sorry because I am new I know my way of questioning is bad, hope I get better. Maybe with the output of the datframe and the shape you can see what I am doing wrong, or what is lacking :)

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, none of the methods you use would work for 32x32x3. If you want to fully utilise the spatial information from the image, you should use [convolutions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_(image_processing)). But this is the more advanced technique.

What you would need is to have the image arrays flattened into an array with 3072 features. I experimented in a shell and if you do `columnaImagenes.append(image.flatten().tolist())` this should give you 3072 sized feature arrays.
If it's not working, I'd suggest to take an element from the column and check it's shape with `np.shape`

But also there's a part of your code where you do the color to grayscale convertion (`cvt_color`). If I understand correctly you are trying to convert the image as BGR where you are actually concatenating is as RGB, which is a different order and grayscale values would actually differ.

Comment: I have edited the question showing some output of how the dataframe looks maybe it will help. Tried to add the line of code you gave me but it did not seem to work.

Comment: @CaMiiN03 what error and what shape of the imagenes column do you get?

Comment: When I do add it like you told me I get a list of 3072 elements, de 3072 pixels. So I guess shape (3072x1), with np.shape it says (3072,). And the error is this exception "ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence." . Here (--> 893     return np.asarray(self._values, dtype)). And here is produced "---> 17 svm.fit(X_train, y_train)"

Comment: Also I get this on top: "TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a real number, not 'list'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)"

Comment: @CaMiiN03 one more thing I could think about is that you labels are strings. Could you try and encode them using LabelEncoder to make them ints instead?

Comment: Now I have the labels as integers between 0-19 and the images as a list of 3072 components and still gives me same exception

Comment: Each image is a list of 3072 elements, containing a value between 0 and 255. And the labels are ints between 0 and 19 identifiyng the category. Then I do X_train = df['imagen']
y_train = df['etiqueta'] and directly give those params to the models. But keep getting the same exception. Value error.setting an array element with a sequence. Maybe is because im passing a pandas column =

Comment: It seems like it does not work because each element of an image for me is a list. So the algorithm somewhere calls float() on the element and causes the error. Either way, if instead of adding the image which is the list I add the number 7 for example, I avoid this exception, but I get this other one instead Expected 2D array, got 1D array instead:
array=[7. 7. 7. ... 7. 7. 7.].
Reshape your data either using array.reshape(-1, 1) if your data has a single feature or array.reshape(1, -1) if it contains a single sample.